# Is there a way to add COLLATE function to set varchar? SQL Server (2012 or 2019)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable varchar (max) that has a regex, originally in a select in the like part it is possible to add the collate part:

```
select name from Names where name like '-., *+&~`;:''"#\/\(\)\\' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 ESCAPE '\'
```

I'm trying to get the escaping my regex in a variable:

```
set @MatchExpression = '-., *+&~`;:''"#\/\(\)\\' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 ESCAPE '\'
```

The SQL Server is giving me the next error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ESCAPE'."

Do you know how to escape **\** and adding the **COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2** into a set of varchar

Comment: `ESCAPE` makes no sense there, you're setting the value of a variable not using a `LIKE`.

Comment: First of all, `LIKE` implements simple patterns, it does *not* implement regex. Second, only `LIKE` has an `ESCAPE` clause. You can't stick `ESCAPE` on just anything. You can have your string include an escape sequence, but then you must remember to put `ESCAPE` everywhere you use it. You're better off using `LIKE`'s own features for quoting special characters, which is surrounding them with `[` and `]` (and only `%`, `_` and `[` even need escaping -- not ``\``, `"` or anything else that might normally be escaped in strings in other languages).